# Time Series stl error

Tags: r, time-series

I have a code that goes like this:

```
rawdata=as.numeric(rawdata)
salesdata_bfr=rawdata[3:(maxcolnum-12)]
print(length(salesdata_bfr))
salesdata_ts=ts(salesdata_bfr, frequency = 12)
salesdata_stl=stl(salesdata_ts,s.window="periodic")
```

`maxcolnum` is equal to 38 and `print(length(salesdata_bfr))` prints 24. But I get the error

```
Error in stl(salesdata_ts, s.window = "periodic") : 
 series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

But I do have a vector of exactly two periods and I specified the frequency in `ts()`. Why won't it work?

Comment: There is a problem somewhere in your code. If `maxcolnum` equals `38`, `3:(maxcolnum-11)` is of length `25`. And using dummy data (`rawdata <- rnorm(38)`), it works. Please post `str(salesdata_bfr)`.

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. I corrected it now. It should be `(maxcolnum-12)`. I wanted to see if it works when it is 25 and it does. `str(salesdata_bfr)` is `num [1:24] 184931 175362 71478 44558 25039 ...`

Comment: Please add `dput(salesdata_bfr)` to your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your code. The following works smoothly:

```
set.seed(42)
maxcolnum <- 38
rawdata <- rnorm(maxcolnum)
salesdata_bfr <- rawdata[3:(maxcolnum-11)]
length(salesdata_bfr)
# [1] 25 <-- it should be 25, not 24
salesdata_ts <- ts(salesdata_bfr, frequency = 12)
salesdata_stl <- stl(salesdata_ts,s.window="periodic")
```